# All homomorphisms from $K_4$ to $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I need to construct all homomorphisms from Klein-4 group $K_4$ to Symmetric group $S_3$. I could construct 10 homomorphisms listed below:

[image]

Are there any more homomorphisms possible to construct?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The Klein-$4$-group $V_4$ is generated by two elements. Thus every homomorphism $V_4 \rightarrow S_3$ is determined by the images of the two generators. How many choices for these images do you have?

Comment: I used the approach you suggested. I really can't identify any more cases I missed out. For instance i tried by taking f(e)=1, f(a)=(12), f(b)=(13), and i got f(ab)=(132). But then order of f(ab)=(132) is 3 and that of ab is 2 and as order of f(ab) doesn't divide order of ab, I suppose its not a homomorphism. Is that the correct way to think?

Comment: @ThorWittich But how do you justify that all of these maps are homomorphisms?